# What's the song heard when Kimura Tatsuya had the epiphany of creating the "Dragonfish Blow"?

Tags: music, hajime-no-ippo

After listen this mix of [Hajime no Ippo - Workout Mix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1azzxb-Hkc), I was thinking about a theme/song heard in a few episodes of Hajime no Ippo, but I recall it heard in this specific episode or OVA:

> Kimura Tatsuya VS Ryo Mashiba<sup>1</sup>

What's the name of the theme/song heard when Kimura Tatsuya had the epiphany of creating a new technique while watching his pet fish, Reiko, jump up and eat its meal in front of him, hence, creating the "Dragonfish Blow"?

---

<sup>1</sup> this fight belongs in the [Execution Arc](https://ippo.fandom.com/wiki/Execution_Arc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/hajimenoippo/comments/kgh1hg/misc_what_is_the_song_heard_in_a_ova_of_hajime_no/) on [r/hajimenoippo](https://www.reddit.com/r/hajimenoippo/) in Reddit and the name of the song is:

> [Hajime No Ippo OST 20 - Arayashiki [HD]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX8mthPC5vY)